# I am having issues Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'some')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am having issues Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'some') in react when try to search a resort or a hotel

Here is the result

1. This is before I hit search button:
   [image]
2. After hit search button the resort come out correctly:
   [image]
3. After select filter Activities and hit search button again:
   [image]
   [image]

Code base from my project:

onSubmit for search button:

```
onSubmit() {
    sessionStorage.remove(ReservationService.APPLIED_POINTS);
    sessionStorage.remove(ReservationService.BOOKED_RESERVATION);
    sessionStorage.remove(ReservationService.CONTRACT_TOOL_TIPS);
    sessionStorage.remove(ReservationService.SELECTED_PREFERENCES);
    const segments = getUniqueContractSegments(this.state.form);

    this.reservationService.search(this.state.form, segments).then((results: Results) => {
        let state: AvailabilityState = this.state;
        state.filters = results.filters;
        state.selectedFilters = this.stripInApplicableFilters(results.filters);
        state.searchResults = results.results;
        state.showResults = true;
        state.hideLoader = true;
        state.loadError = false;
        state.resultsError = false;
        state.selectedMonth = state.form.startDate;
        this.setState(state);
    }).catch((error: any) => {
        if (!handle401Error(error)) {
            let state: AvailabilityState = this.state;
            state.hideLoader = true;
            state.resultsError = true;
            state.searchResultsErrorMessage = error.message ? `${error.message}` : "Unspecified error";
            this.setState(state);
            log.error(`Error: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
        }
    });

    this.setState({hideLoader: false, availability: {form: Object.assign({}, this.state.form)}});
    sessionStorage.write(ReservationService.OPS_FORM_SESSION_KEY, JSON.stringify(this.state.form));
}
```

Here is onFilter for filter select in checkbox:

```
   onFilterSelect(name: string, item: any) {
        let selectedFilters: SelectedFilters = {...this.state.selectedFilters};
        const selectedFilter = {...selectedFilters[name]};
        const idx = selectedFilter.filters.indexOf(item);

        if (idx > -1) {
            selectedFilter.filters = selectedFilter.filters.filter((filterOption: string) => filterOption !== item);
        } else {
            selectedFilter.filters = [...selectedFilter.filters, item];

            // If filter group isn't expanded, expand.
            // User could be changing filter from room-type pills.
            if (!selectedFilter.expanded) {
                selectedFilter.expanded = true;
            }
        }
        selectedFilters[name] = selectedFilter;

        this.setState({ selectedFilters });
        console.log("Filter: ", selectedFilters)
    }
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this error happens when you want to read a property from an object that has no value (is undefined) so there is a simple solution you can put `?` before `.` like `Object?.Property` it cause when an object is an undefined property does not read

may be there :

```js
const idx = selectedFilter?.filters?.indexOf(item);

        if (idx > -1) {
            selectedFilter.filters = selectedFilter?.filters?.filter((filterOption: string) => filterOption !== item);
        } else {
            selectedFilter.filters = [...selectedFilter.filters, item];
```